# Memory leak openai library

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, openai-api

```
async def ask(question,api_key,old):
client = AsyncClient(
    api_key=api_key
)
try:
    stream = await client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
        messages=old + [{"role": "user", "content": question}],
        stream=True
    )
    return {'stream':stream,'client':client}
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    await client.close()
    if 'Error code: 429' in e.args[0]:
        db.delete_token_from_file(api_key)
    return 0

async def get_gpt_stream_answer(user_id, promt, old, i, message_to_edit: types.Message):
print("Вопрос задался")
if i >= 3:
    print(f"{user_id} Не получил ответ")
    db.clear_chat(user_id)
    return 0
if len(old) > 10:
    old = old[-10:]
token = get_random_token()
data = await gpt.ask(promt, token, old)
if data == 0:
    print(f"{user_id} Попытка #{i}")
    return (await get_gpt_stream_answer(user_id, promt, old, i + 1, message_to_edit))
try:
    response_text = ""
    speed = 100
    i = 0
    async for chunk in data['stream']:
        response_text += chunk.choices[0].delta.content or ""
        if i >= speed:
            try:
                await message_to_edit.edit_text(
                    text=response_text
                )
            except Exception as e:
                if 'Message_too_long' in e.args[0]:
                    break
            i = 0
        i+=1
    await message_to_edit.edit_text(
        text=response_text
    )
    db.insert_new_message(user_id, 'user', promt,None)
    db.insert_new_message(user_id, 'assistant', response_text,None)
    return response_text
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    db.clear_chat(user_id)
    db.plus_error(token)
    db.delete_token_if(token)
    return 0
finally:
    if 'client' in data.keys():
        await data['client'].close()
```

Two methods for the interaction of a Telegram bot and GPT-3.5 TURBO. There is a memory leak caused by the openai _response method. I've been looking for a reason for a week. Still can't find it.

I tried to find the memory leak using the tracemalloc library and identified that it occurs due to the _response method in the OpenAI library. Perhaps I am not closing the stream properly, and that's the problem.